# How to read all "last_changed" records from Firebird DB?

Tags: sql, triggers, firebird

My question is a bit tricky, because it's mostly a logical problem.
I've tried to optimize my app speed by reading everything into memory but only those records, which changed since *"last read"* = greatest timestamp of records last time loaded.

FirebirdSQL database engine does not allow to update a field in an "After Trigger" directly, so it's obviously using "before update or insert" triggers to update the field `new.last_changed = current_timestamp;`

### The problem:

As it turns out, this is a totally WRONG method, because those triggers fire on transaction **start**!
So if there is a transaction that takes some more time than an other, the saved "last changed time" will be lower than a short-burst transaction fired and finished in between.
`1. tr.:  13:00:01.400 .............................Commit`  << this record will be skipped !
`2. tr.:           13:00.01.500......Commit` << reading of data will happen here.
The next read will be `>= 13:00.01.500`

### I've tried:

to rewrite all triggers, so they fire **after** and call an `UPDATE orders SET ...` << *but this causing circular, self-calling endless events.*
Would a `SET_CONTEXT` [lock](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9290926) interfere with **multi-row** update and **nested** triggers?
 *(I do not see any possibility this method would work **good** if running multiple updates in the same transaction.)*

What is the common solution for all this?

### Edit1:

What I want to happen is to read **only** those records from DB actually changed since last read. For that to happen, I need the engine to update records AFTER COMMIT. (Not during it, "in the middle".)
This trigger is NOT good, because it will fire on the moment of change, (not after Commit):

```
alter trigger SYNC_ORDERS active after insert or update position 999 AS
declare variable N timestamp; 
begin
  N = cast('NOW' as timestamp);
  if (new.last_changed <> :N) then
    update ORDERS set last_changed= :N where ID=new.ID;
end
```

And from the application I do:

```
Query1.SQL.Text := 'SELECT * FROM orders WHERE last_changed >= ' + DateTimeToStr( latest_record );  
Query1.Open;  
 latest_record := Query1.FieldByName('last_changed').asDateTime;
```

*.. this code will list only the record commited in the 2th transaction (earlier) and never the first, longer running transaction (commited later).*

### Edit2:

It seems I have the same question as [here...](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3809751/determining-row-changes-since-last-access-in-sql-server) , but specially for FirebirdSQL.
There are not really any good solutions there, but gave me an idea:
- What if I create an extra table and log changes earlier than 5 minutes there per table?
- Before each SQL query, first I will ask for any changes in that table, sequenced via ID grow!
- Delete lines older than 23 hours

```
ID  TableID  Changed
===========================
1   5   2019.11.27 19:36:21
2   5   2019.11.27 19:31:19
```

### Edit3:

As Arioch already suggested, one solution is to:

- create a "logger table" filled on every `BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE`
  trigger by every table
- and update the "last_changed" sequence of it
  by the `ON TRANSACTION COMMIT` trigger

But, would not be ...

### a better approach?:

- adding 1-1 `last_sequence INT64 DEFAULT NULL` column to every table
- create a global generator `LAST_GEN`
- update every table's every NULL row with a gen_id(LAST_GEN,1) inside the `ON TRANSACTION COMMIT` trigger
- SET to NULL again on every `BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE` trigger

So basically switching the `last_sequence` column of a record to:
 `NULL > 1 > NULL > 34` ... every time it gets modified.
This way I :

- do not have to fill the DB with log data,
- and I can query the tables directly with `WHERE last_sequence>1;`.
- No needed to pre-query the "logger table" first.

I'm just afraid: WHAT happens, if the `ON TRANSACTION COMMIT` trigger is trying to update a `last_sequence` field, **while** a 2th transaction's ON BEFORE trigger is locking the record (of an other table)?
Can this happen at all?

Comment: I think I see the problem, but your narrative is a bit unclear to me.  Can you show us a very simple table with a handful of rows, the triggers you've tried, and what you want to happen?

Comment: @pilcrow "Edit1" added. Explained goal with other words. Added little code example. IMHO since this problem effecting ALL kinds of tables with all rows, an example of that does not explain anything.

Comment: You may try to use `ON COMMIT` trigger. https://firebirdsql.org/refdocs/langrefupd21-ddl-trigger.html

Comment: @Arioch'The I was thinking about that too, but there is no way to tell what happened at that transaction. (Was it a simple `SELECT`? What tables changed? What records changed if any at all?)

Comment: Triggers don't fire on transaction start (except for the `TRANSACTION START` database trigger), they fire on row modification. @Arioch'The A `ON TRANSACTION COMMIT` is not associated with a table, so it will be hard to use to update timestamps on rows.

Comment: In any case, this is not an easy problem to solve, except maybe by using isolation level `SNAPSHOT TABLE STABILITY` and taking the associated hit in throughput and other problems (and I'm not even sure this will solve all those problems). In Firebird 3 you could try to use `RDB$RECORD_VERSION`, but even there you might not see all updates, as that will just contain the transaction number that changed the record, so a long running transaction that finally commits might not be visible to you because you've already seen records with a higher version.

Comment: Maybe you could use `ON TRANSACTION COMMIT` to record the time that a specific transaction committed, and then use the transaction id and `RDB$RECORD_VERSION` to track the records that were updated by that transaction.

Comment: Rought scheme would be per-table triggers logging which records were updated or inserted **or deleted** into some clear-on-commit `GTT` or into some persistent table and there marked with Transaction ID (`current_transaction`). Then `ON COMMIT` trigger would re-mark those records (including deleted ones) by the timestamp.

Comment: Maybe you'd better drop 2-tier model and switch to 3-teir one. Database -> Application Server -> Multiple Clients. Then it should be AS keeping state which client had which data briefcase and how to replicate last moment changes to those clients.

Comment: @Arioch'The *"Then ON COMMIT trigger would re-mark those records"* >> That's exactly I've started to working on :-) That would minimize the amount of data needs to be red. (I'm going to fill secondary sequence + new TimeStamps at ON COMMIT trigger to keep track.)

Comment: @Arioch'The  *switch to 3-teir model* >> YES, that's a long-term plan. Drop the 17year old APP and start a new from scratch

Comment: @MarkRotteveel Thanks, but I'm still working with FB2.5,  so 3.0 features are not available. A separate "logger table" will be the solution, as Arioch suggested.

Comment: @SzakiLaci don't forget about updating DELETED rows too, both clients to server and server to clients

Comment: Also, if you would choose standard table instead of GTT, then consider adding there `current_user` column and just keeping all rows in the logger table for at least a year. So if your customer would need "who done it???" retroactive investigation - you have some changes history.

Comment: @Arioch'The Thanks for the hints! I NEVER really DELETE anything, but mark as "deleted" with a timestamp. *And yes, it is important to see which waiter is trying to steel...etc. ;-) There are several methods to log those events.*

Comment: Added "Edit3"... listing and asking about 2 possible solutions.

Comment: Found this: RDB$RECORD_VERSION https://www.ibphoenix.com/resources/documents/contributed/doc_393  Seems to be what I need. Sadly it's only available from FB3.0 up, not for FB version 2.5.

Comment: @SzakiLaci but you can simulate it in `before update or insert` triggers, storing `current_transaction` value. Or, rather, some generator that you would increase on TX start and save into `RDB$SET_CONTEXT('USER_TRANSACTION'...` or some per-transaction `GTT`. (I think TX id counter is reset on Firebird server shutdown or maybe even database unloading (all connection closed and grace pause in FB3 expired)), so you can not persits `current_transaction` directly.  /// I just was saying, if you already aim at adding logging, then u may log user too, as added bonus, almost free

Comment: @Arioch'The You are right,  I could simply save TX number: `CURRENT_TRANSACTION`, but it would not help, since they START at an unknown time I can not get information later about, when it's already closed. That's why they have implemented into the FB3 engine the `RDB$RECORD_VERSION` variable to keep track of that. ### And NO, TX number is a continuous increment field, that is nullified ONLY on DB restore. Since it's only 32bit in FB2.5, it caused many problems at big companies having 2B TX in a few month. It has been increased at FB3.0 to 48 bit.

Comment: My bad, was in hurry, so mistook CURRENT_CONNECTION and CURRENT_TRANSACTION // your link says "The value returned is the number of the transaction that created the record version" - so i fail to see why RDB$VERSION is essentially different from saving CURRENT_TRANSACTION by triggers. ISTM that would be exactly the same pre-row value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The final solution is based on the idea, that:

1. Each table's `BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE` trigger can push a time of the transaction: `RDB$SET_CONTEXT('USER_TRANSACTION', 'table31', current_timestamp`);
2. The global `ON TRANSACTION COMMIT` trigger can insert a sequence + time into a "logging table", if receiving such a context.
3. It can even take care of "daylight saving changes" and "intervals", by logging only "big time differences", like >=1 minute, to reduce the amount of records.)
4. A stored procedure can ease and speed up the calculation of 'LAST_QUERY_TIME' of each query's.

### Example:

1.)

```sql
create trigger ORDERS_BI active before insert or update position 0 AS
BEGIN
  IF (NEW.ID IS NULL) THEN
    NEW.ID = GEN_ID(GEN_ORDERS,1);
  RDB$SET_CONTEXT('USER_TRANSACTION', 'orders_table', current_timestamp);  
END
```

2, 3.)

```sql
create trigger TRG_SYNC_AFTER_COMMIT ACTIVE ON transaction commit POSITION 1 as 
  declare variable N TIMESTAMP;
  declare variable T VARCHAR(255);
begin
  N = cast('NOW' as timestamp);
  T = RDB$GET_CONTEXT('USER_TRANSACTION', 'orders_table');

  if (:T is not null) then begin
    if (:N < :T) then T = :N; --system time changed eg.: daylight saving" -1 hour
    if (datediff(second from :T to :N) > 60 ) then --more than 1min. passed
      insert into "SYNC_PAST_TIMES" (ID, TABLE_NUMBER, TRG_START, SYNC_TIME, C_USER)
        values (GEN_ID(GEN_SYNC_PAST_TIMES, 1), 31, cast(:T as timestamp), :N, CURRENT_USER);
  end;  

-- other tables too:
  T = RDB$GET_CONTEXT('USER_TRANSACTION', 'details_table');
-- ...

  when any do EXIT;
end
```

## Edit1:

It is possible to speed up the readout of the "last-time-changed" value from our `SYNC_PAST_TIMES` table with a help of a Stored Procedure. Logically, You have to store in memory both the ID `PT_ID` + the time `PT_TM` in your program to call it for each table.

```sql
CREATE PROCEDURE SP_LAST_MODIF_TIME (
    TABLE_NUMBER SM_INT,
    LAST_PASTTIME_ID BG_INT,
    LAST_PASTTIME TIMESTAMP)
RETURNS (
    PT_ID BG_INT,
    PT_TM TIMESTAMP)
AS
  declare variable TEMP_TIME TIMESTAMP;
  declare variable TBL       SMALLINT;
begin

  PT_TM   = :LAST_PASTTIME;
  FOR SELECT p.ID, p.SYNC_TIME, p.TABLA FROM SYNC_PAST_TIMES p WHERE (p.ID > :LAST_PASTTIME_ID)
    ORDER by p.ID ASC
    INTO PT_ID, TEMP_TIME, TBL DO --the PT_ID gets an increasing value immediately
  begin
    if (:TBL = :TABLE_NUMBER) then
      if (:TEMP_TIME< :MI_TIME) then 
        PT_TM = :TEMP_TIME; --searching for the smallest
  end
  
  if (:PT_ID IS NULL) then begin
    PT_ID  = :LAST_PASTTIME_ID;
    PT_TM = :LAST_PASTTIME;
  end
  
  suspend;
END
```

You can use this procedure by including in your select, using the `WITH .. AS` format:

```sql
with UTLS as (select first 1 PT_ID, PT_TM from SP_LAST_MODIF_TIME (55, -- TABLE_NUMBER
  0, '1899.12.30 00:00:06.000') ) -- last PT_ID, PT_TM from your APP 
  select first 1000 u.PT_ID, current_timestamp as NOWWW, r.*
  from UTLS u, "Orders" r
  where (r.SYNC_TIME >= u.PT_TM);
```

Using `FIRST 1000` is a must to prevent reading the whole table if all values are changed at once.
*Upgrading the SQL, adding a new column, etc. makes `SYNC_TIME` changing to `NOW` at the same time at all rows of the table.*
You may adjust it per table individually, just like the interval of seconds to monitor changes. Add a **check** to your APP, how to handle the case, if the new data reaches 1000 lines at once ...

Comment: How do you read then consistent delta of records? This approach do not allow it. You still need to read all records. Only what you now know from this solution is that you must do refetch.

Comment: @Livius : Added a "read record" example as "Edit1". This method works at 50+ DBs daily since 2 years. The read is triggered by 1-1 Firebird Event + also every X minute once as safeguard, if an event would go missing and no readout happened since than.

Comment: How do you set new value for Orders.SYNC_TIME? In the trigger? As i do not see it in above trigger. you have it in `from UTLS u, "Orders" r  where (r.SYNC_TIME >= u.PT_TM);`

Comment: @Livius No. That trigger is not here, because it is a very basic one, and each table needs it differently. I thought it is obvious at this level of FB knowledge. If not, those should not start implementing such complicated things, because it would be too hard for them or too much possible mistakes can happen. Example: `AFTER INSERT OR UPDATE ... IF (NEW.somevalue <> OLD.somevalue or ... NEW. ... ) NEW.SYNC_TIME = current_timestamp; ...` . Also it is importantant that you never delete any record, just mark them as `hidden = 1;`. FB4+ has auto-sync-feature, which is much easier to use.

Comment: I have confirmed now that this solution do not work. Create table ORDERS insert 5 rows. Run client applications CA1, CA2 and CA3. CA1 start transaction T1 and update row 1 and 2 of orders table (do not commit) start CA3 and fetch all data. Start CA2 start transaction T2 update row 3 and 4. do commit T2. CA3 fetch delta - it is ok. But now commit transaction T1. CA3 fetch delta, hmm surprise, nothing fetched. Please show real solution and put in e.g. https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=firebird_3.0

Comment: @Livius I'm not familiar with fiddle yet good enough to make a complete example. But you can open a ticket here and share your code, so we can see what you have done wrong. put a link here. This solution works everywhere stable and fast.

Comment: did you tested my above scenario on your implementation?